# How do I turn off the alt-shift-uparrow keybinding in GNOME?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, compiz, shortcut-keys

After upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04, the key sequence <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> now seems to have a window-manager level definition.

It seems that this is a new unity key sequence. However, I'm using
"Classic Ubuntu" on login - i.e. I'm using Gnome. Nevertheless, this new key sequence
has its Unity functionality.

I'm an emacs user (where <kbd>Meta</kbd>=<kbd>ALT</kbd>), and <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> is a key sequence that I use fairly often (manipulating tables in org-mode). So I'd like to know how to turn off this
Unity/Gnome keybinding, so that emacs actually sees this key sequence.

As far as I can see, this keybinding (<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>UpArrow</kbd>) is *not* mentioned in the Gnome "Keyboard Shortcuts" tool (available from the System->Preferences menu).

Comment: @Jorge: thanks for the edit. I only mentioned 11.04 because the problem appeared *exactly* upon upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer but I am reasonably certain that this shortcut is found in the compiz tools, not GNOME's tools.

Comment: @Jorge: Perfect; thanks.  After installing CompizConfig settings manager, turned off "scale" window management option, and the keybinding is now off.

Comment: Please write your resolution in an answer and accept it, since your problem is solved. Otherwise, your question will still show up in the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Dash Home -> CompizConfig Settings Manager-> Scale(icon) under Windows Management Category -> Bindings(tab) -> Initiate Windows Picker -> change to <Shift><Super>Up

Done.

Comment: Thanks, but that's rather f*cked up method of handling short cut keys. I've just spend 15 minutes looking for the ^&*^&^* thing, no search capacity either. Maybe the Ubuntu devs should take a closer look at how Eclipse handles short cut keys.